# Compactness for a set of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a open set and write $\Omega=\cup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i$, where $Q_i$ is a compact set. Define in $L_{loc}^p(\Omega)$ the metric $d(f,g)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\min\Big(\frac{1}{2^k},\|f-g\|_{L^p(Q_k)}\Big)$.

Let $p\in [1,\infty)$, $F\subset L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$ and define $F_k=\{f\chi_{Q_k}:\ f\in F\}$, where $\chi_{A}$ is the characteristic function of $A$. Suppose that for each $k$, the set $F_k$ is totally bounded in $L^p(\Omega)$. How can one show that $F$ is totally bounded?

My try: Fix $\epsilon>0$ and choose $n$ such that $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. For each $k=1,...,n$ consider the $\frac{\epsilon}{k+1}$-net $\phi_1^k,...,\phi_{n(k)}^k$ of $F_k$, where $n(k)$ is a natural number depending on $k$.

Consider the set $K$ of all "possible" sequences of the form: $(A_1,A_2,...,A_n)$, where each $A_k$ is a element chosen from the $\frac{\epsilon}{k+1}$-net $\phi_1^k,...,\phi_{n(k)}^k$ (for example $(\phi_2^1,\phi_1^2,...,\phi^n_4)$). Note that $K$ is finite. Enumerate $K=\{U_1,...,U_r\}$ and let's say that $f\in L_{loc}^p(\Omega)$ is in $U_i=(A_1,...,A_n)$, if $\|f\chi_{Q_1}-A_1\|_{Q_1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$,...,$\|f\chi_{Q_{n}}-A_n\|_{Q_n}<\frac{\epsilon}{n+1}$ $\Big($ for instance, if $U_i=(\phi_2^1,\phi_1^2,...,\phi^n_4)$, then I am asking that $\|f\chi_{Q_1}-\phi_2^1\|_{Q_1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$,...,$\|f\chi_{Q_{n}}-\phi^n_4\|_{Q_n}<\frac{\epsilon}{n+1}\Big)$.

For each $i=1,...,r$ choose a $f_i\in F$, such that $f_i\in U_i$.

We claim that the set $f_i$ is an $\epsilon$-net for $F$. Indeed, if $f\in F$, then $f\in U_i$ for some $i$, hence \begin{eqnarray}
 d(f,f_i) &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty\min\Big(\frac{1}{2^k},\|f-f_i\|_{L^p(Q_k)}\Big)      \nonumber \\
   &\leq& \sum_{i=1}^n\|f-f_i\|_{Q_k}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \nonumber \\
   &<& \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

If you have patience to read my proof, please verify if it is correct.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $p$?

Comment: Yes, let me add it, I forgot.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but I don't see it: If $F_1,F_2$ are totally bounded, is it true that $F_1 \cup F_2$ is totally bounded?

Comment: I think yes: Given $\epsilon>0$, Let $F_1\subset\cup U_i$ and $F_2\subset \cup V_i$ where $U_i$ and $V_i$ are sets of diameter less then $\epsilon$. Then, $F_1\cup F_2\subset (\cup U_i)\cup (\cup V_i)$. Is this right @copper.hat ?

Comment: You are correct. However, I didn't express myself correctly. I need to think a bit more about what I meant to ask!

Comment: I want the $\epsilon$-net for $F_1 \cup F_2$ to work for both at the same time. That is, a set $\Phi \subset F$ such that if $f \in F$, then there is a $\phi \in \Phi$ such that both $\|f-\phi\|_{Q_k} < \epsilon$. Just taking unions of the separate $\epsilon$-nets doesn't guarantee that one function will approximate both at the same time. (At least its not obvious to me.)

Comment: I'm stuck. I want to show that for a finite number of $F_k$ and $\epsilon>0$ that there exists a subset of $F$ that serves as a 'uniform' $\epsilon$-net for the $F_k$ (uniform in the sense that one element of the net will be uniformly close in the $\|\cdot\|_{Q_i}$ metric). Just a thought; I wonder if we can use Tychonoff here?

Comment: A finite subset $N$ such that every other element is a distance less than $\epsilon$ away from some element of $N$.

Comment: If the $Q_i$ are increasing it can work, but I need some uniformity...

Comment: I don't follow why the $Q_1$ pseudo-metric is bounded by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Well, if the $Q_i$ are increasing, that solves a problem. It means an $\epsilon$-net for $F_k$ is automatically an $\epsilon$-net for $F_1,...,F_{k-1}$. I don't get why the metrics are equivalent otherwise. With increasing $Q_i$, we have $\|\cdot\|_{Q_k} \le \| \cdot \|_{Q_{k+1}}$.

Comment: I don't follow some of it.

Comment: Let's gonna delete the comment to avoid confusion @copper.hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer because of an additional assumption I made.

I will assume that the $Q_i$ are increasing. The main import of this assumption is that we have $\|x\|_{L^p(Q_{k})} \le \|x\|_{L^p(Q_{k+1})}$, hence an $\epsilon$-net for $F_k$ is (appropriately adjusted) also an $\epsilon$-net for $F_1,...,F_{k-1}$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and choose $n$ such that $\sum_{k>n} \frac{1}{2^k} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $F_n$ is totally bounded, there is a finite $\frac{\epsilon}{2n}$-net $\phi_1,...,\phi_p$. Each $\phi_i$ has the form $\phi_i = f_i 1_{Q_n}$ for some $f_i \in F$. Then I claim that $f_1,...,f_p$ is an $\epsilon$-net for $F$ (appropriately adjusted).

Let $f \in F$. Choose $\phi_j$ such that $\|f-\phi_j\|_{L^p(Q_n)} < \frac{\epsilon}{2n}$. Let $f_j$ be the corresponding element of $F$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
d(f,f_j) &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty\min ( \frac{1}{2^k},\|f-f_j\|_{L^p(Q_k)} ) \\
&\le& \sum_{k=1}^n \|f-f_j\|_{L^p(Q_k)} + \sum_{k>n} \frac{1}{2^k} \\
&<& \sum_{k=1}^n \|f-\phi_j\|_{L^p(Q_n)} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&<& \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $f_1,...,f_p$ is an $\epsilon$-net for $F$.

Comment: I have changed my proof based on yours, maybe now it is readable. If you have some time, please try to read it and verify if it is correct. Thank you @cooper.

Comment: Hi @Tomás; I think there is still a gap in the proof. The issue is how to piece together the elements of $F_k$ into a single function $f_i$. That is why I needed nesting above.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. This issue is giving me on the head.

Comment: Where did the problem arise from?

Comment: Take a look in the proof of corollary 8. http://www.math.ntnu.no/conservation/2009/037.pdf

Comment: Do you know why they use precompact for Corollary 8, but totally bounded for everything preceding? (Also, it looks like it would be fine to assume the $Q_i$ are nested?)

Comment: If a set is totally bounded, then its closure is compact, hence I dont see any reason for the change of terms. Yes for the purpose of demonstrate the corollary, we can assume your hypothesis. I was just curious about the other cases.

Comment: I understand now, precompact was used in Corollary 8 because there is no metric in that case (a collection of pseudo-metrics instead).

Comment: This is strange, now I saw it. I have another version here. I will send to your e-mail, because I can't find it on internet.

Comment: Excellent thanks! The $K_k$ sets in the paper are nested. I think that the $Q_i$ need to have the property that any compact set is contained in some $Q_i$.

Comment: But there they write: "Write $\Omega$ as a union of compact sets" and then they give an example. It's seems for me that any union is possible. Then, they say that any compact set is contained in some $K_k$, so it is sufficient to consider only the sets $K_k$.

Comment: Where do they characterize $\Omega$ (other than the remark before Cor. 8)? I think the challenge is to show that if Cor. 8 (ii) is true on **some** collection of compact sets (say $Q_i$), then Cor. 8 (ii) is true on **any** compact subset of $\cup_i Q_i$. It seems reasonable, but I can't muster a proof...